# Работа с текстовыми потоками

Tags: c#, потоки-данных

Как мне прописать код, который меняет текст во всех `.txt` файлах находящихся в одной директории с приложением? То есть если я софт закинул в папку, то после запуска софта, софт меняет текст в папке куда я его забросил.

Comment: Скорее всего Вам нужно почитать статью о работе с файлами, например [тут](http://vbbook.ru/visual-c.net/rabota-s-faiylami-na-c/)

Comment: а причем тут это? Куда кинул exe, путь там и работает

Comment: Тогда значит я ничего не понял. Могли бы Вы описать более подробно задачу.

Comment: `меняет текст во всех txt-файлах куда я положу софт` <-- меняет на что? А что до этого было в файле? Без примера дело не пойдет.

Comment: Скорее всего у вас это не получится. Под Windows софт обычно инсталлируется в каталог, не доступный на модификацию обычному пользователю. Вы должны класть изменяемые файлы в каталог `%APPDATA%\Имя Вашего Приложения`.

Comment: К примеру в рар архиве есть 5 txt файлов в них цифра, к примеру 10. Мне надо эту 10-тку заменить на цифру 4. И сохранить их там же, пусть exe мне перепакует с максимальным сжатием. Все

Comment: @May_be: Вы понимаете, что «текстовый файл» и «текстовый файл в rar-архиве» — это **очень** разные вещи? Небось архив ещё и с паролем?

Comment: без пароля......

Answer (score 3):

Вот держите накидал для вас программу, думаю дальше реализуете требования сами.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace TextRoot.ConsoleApplication
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            var finder = new TextFileFinder();
            var editor = new FileEditor(finder);

            //var inputFile = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "question.txt");
            //editor.EditOne(inputFile, textLine => Regex.Replace(textLine, "(.*):", "P$@*#!"));

            var inputDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
            editor.EditAll(inputDirectory, textLine => Regex.Replace(textLine, "(.*):", "P$@*#!"));

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class FileEditor
    {
        private readonly TextFileFinder _finder;
        private readonly List<string> _editedTextLines;

        public FileEditor(TextFileFinder finder)
        {
            _finder = finder;

            _editedTextLines = new List<string>();
        }

        public void EditOne(string filePath, Func<string, string> change)
        {
            try
            {
                MakeChanges(filePath, change);
                SaveChanges(filePath);

                Console.WriteLine($"Text in '{filePath}' was changed.");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        public void EditAll(string directoryPath, Func<string, string> change)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (var file in _finder.FindAll(directoryPath))
                    EditOne(file.FullName, change);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        #region Private Helpers

        private void MakeChanges(string filePath, Func<string, string> change)
        {
            using (var file = _finder.Find(filePath).OpenRead())
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(file))
            {
                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    var textLine = reader.ReadLine();
                    _editedTextLines.Add(change(textLine));
                }
            }
        }

        private void SaveChanges(string filePath)
        {
            using (var file = _finder.Find(filePath).Open(FileMode.Truncate))
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(file))
            {
                foreach (var line in _editedTextLines)
                    writer.WriteLine(line);

                _editedTextLines.Clear();
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }

    public class TextFileFinder
    {
        public FileInfo Find(string filePath)
        {
            var fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(filePath);

            if (fileExtension != ".txt")
                throw new NotSupportedException($"File extension '{fileExtension}' is not supported.");

            var fileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);

            if (!fileInfo.Exists)
                throw new FileNotFoundException();

            return fileInfo;
        }

        public IEnumerable<FileInfo> FindAll(string directoryPath)
        {
            var directory = new DirectoryInfo(directoryPath);
            return directory.GetFiles("*.txt");
        }
    }
}
```

Для изменения содержимого файла используйте регулярное выражение 
`Regex.Replace(text, "Шаблон", "Замена")`.

### Рекомендации касательно обработки строк

[Элементы языка регулярных выражений — краткий справочник](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: утром проверю, то есть  куда я ее закину а именно в рар архив, то exe мне заменить текст на другой текст во всех txt файлах? Вы так написали код, да?

Comment: Да именно так только не забудьте запустить программу из архива.

Comment: @May_be если txt файлы находятся в rar'е, то txt файлы надо распаковать/извлечь из архива,

Comment: @AndrewPavlyuk конечно, полезно губить свежие умы решениями, но все же не решать же все))))

Comment: @dDevil ну я оставил пространство для размышлений в контексте регулярных выражений ...)))

Comment: Andrey Идеально, вот прямо то что мне надо, Вы мне столько времени с экономили, что прямо я не знаю.....